# Datatype similar to arrays, Mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm making a table where I need to have a field of allowed users, but there isn't an "array" data-type in mysql. Is there a similar data-type that would store my users in a list fashion? I've heard of a BLOB but I'm not too sure if thats what I'm looking for.

Comment: wrong way of thinking about it... create a new child table to store your users list. storing multiple independent bits of data in a single field is a bad way to go. hard to maintain, hard to deal with, and will just lead to future maintainers leaving bags of flaming dog poop on your front step when they come in to clean up the mess.

Comment: any tutorial that you could point me to? I'm fairly new to mysql and php. Thanks.

Comment: Look up first normal form (1NF). And the second and third, while you're at it, they're usually good ideas as well.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 0):

That's a fairly simple design:

```
folder
======
folder_id
folder_name

user
====
user_id
user_name

grant
=====
folder_id
user_id
```

As about [BLOB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html):

> A BLOB is a binary large object that can hold a variable amount of data [...] BLOB values are treated as binary strings (byte strings). They have no character set, and sorting and comparison are based on the numeric values of the bytes in column values.

A binary column is not a good option to store text.